# I can't see preview of camera when starting activity on android

Tags: android, camera, video-capture, preview

Update:
I could solve the rotation issue (I will write modified code later by an answer). But I can't see preview of camera when starting activity still. 
I read below links but didn’t help me.
[Can't create Camera preview in onCreate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239440/cant-create-camera-preview-in-oncreate)
[Android camera preview in surfaceview2]

### Modify my code if you know any response please.

//-------------------------------------------

I have an android app with below code for capture videos. Every things works correctly except 2 things.
First is : I can't  have preview for Camera before capturing. Means I want have a preview by my camera when VideoRecorderActivity1 is started.
Second: when I press start for ToggleButton, then every things rotates 90 degree that is very bad. But output file has correct degree for show. You can use from below code and see result.
Please help and solve my  apps issue.Thanks.
Here is my Classess.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class VideoRecorderActivity1 extends Activity 
implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{

private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private SurfaceView surfaceView;
public MediaRecorder mrec= new MediaRecorder();

private Camera mCamera;
private ToggleButton mToggleButton=null;
private String Videname="";
private String Videopath="";
private VideoRecorder myVideo=null;
private static Boolean isRecording=false;
String  filePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator
+"My Audios"+File.separator+"video2camera5.3gpp";
private Boolean ExistVideo(String path1)
{
 File   file = new File(SDcard.Dir_recordedVideos );
   File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {           
        if(list[i].getPath().equals(path1))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recorder_video);
    InitializeUI();
    mToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
              if (((ToggleButton) v).isChecked())

                  try 
                  {    myVideo=new VideoRecorder();
                    do{
                        myVideo.setName();
                        Videname=myVideo.getName();
                        myVideo.setPath();
                        Videopath=myVideo.getPath();
                      }while(ExistVideo(Videopath));

                     startRecording();
                    } 
                  catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        String message = e.getMessage();
                        Log.i(null, "Problem Start"+message);
                        if(mrec!= null)
                        mrec.release();
                    }

                else 
                    stopRecording();
        }
    });
}

 protected void startRecording() throws IOException 
 {
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
    {
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
    }

    // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
    File directory = new File(this.Videopath).getParentFile();

    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) 
    {
        throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }

   mrec = new MediaRecorder();  // Works well
    mCamera.unlock();

    mrec.setCamera(mCamera);
    mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());   
    mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    mrec.setOutputFile(Videopath);

    mrec.prepare();
    isRecording=true;
    mrec.start();
}
protected void stopRecording() 
{
    if(mrec !=null)
        mrec.stop();
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    isRecording=false;
}
private void releaseMediaRecorder()
{
    if (mrec != null) 
    {
        mrec.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
        mrec.release(); // release the recorder object
        mrec = null;
        mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
    }
}
private void releaseCamera()
{
    if (mCamera != null)
    {
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
//------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
{
    if (mCamera != null)
    {
       Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
       mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }
    else
    {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      VideoRecorderActivity1.this.finish();
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
{

}
//------------------------------------------------------------
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
 {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) 
      {              
          if(isRecording)
              mCamera.stopPreview();
           mCamera.release();

        VideoRecorderActivity1.this.finish();
      }

      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
//------------------------------------------------------------
 private void InitializeUI()
 {
       mCamera = Camera.open();
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface()); 
        mToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleRecordingButton);
 }
```

}

And import this Class:

```
public class VideoRecorder 
{
private String name="";
private static int id=0;
private String path=null;

public VideoRecorder()
{

}
public String getName() 
{
    return(this.name);
}   
public void setName() 
{
    id++;
    this.name="video "+id;
} 
    public String getPath()
    {
        return this.path;
    }

    public void setPath() 
    {
        if (!this.name.contains(".")) 
        {
            this.name += ".3gpp";
        }
       this.path=SDcard.Dir_recordedVideos + this.name;

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating the preview i think, in your surface created code put this:

```
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            Log.v(TAG,"in surfaceCreated");                                 //Surface created for video preview and playback
            try{
                    mCamera .setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                    mCamera .startPreview();
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                    Log.v(TAG,"could not start the preview ");
                    e.printStackTrace();

            }

    }
```

In your startrecording function do it like this:

```
protected void startRecording() throws IOException 
{
String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
{
    throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
}

// make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
File directory = new File(this.Videopath).getParentFile();

if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) 
{
    throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
}

  mcamera.stopPreview();
  mcamera.unlock();
  mrec = new MediaRecorder();  // Works well
  mrec.setCamera(mCamera);   
 mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
 mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
 mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
 mrec.setOutputFile(Videopath);
 mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());   
 mrec.prepare();
 isRecording=true;
 mrec.start();
}
```

Comment: remove  mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());  from  InitializeUI()

Comment: ofcource i now test it.and talk to you result

Comment: please see and help me for this question.this question you responsed not solved very well.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330621/how-i-can-have-previewing-permanently-when-capture-video-foe-android